# z-index highlights image on click

Tags: html, css

I've run into a bit of an issue while using z-index. When I add z-index to an id so that it does not overlap another div I have, it makes the image highlight on click, like it would on a double click.

This only happens in Firefox. In Chrome and IE 9,8 and 7, it does not highlight on click. I am using Firefox 17.0.1. What might be causing this? My ids CSS looks like this:

```
#brand-content, #brand-content>img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position: relative;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

The HTML I have on the page is just:

```
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php
      include ("../includes/sidebar.php");
     ?>
     <div id="brand-content">
      <img src="../images/IMG_78707.jpg">
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you give us some HTML?

Comment: `z-index: -1` is invalid. Show your HTML. If possible, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I've added the HTML. There isn't much there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I've fixed this issue by changing my sidebar to have a z-index as well as the brand-content div. They both have positive numbers and the image no longer highlights on click. I still would like to know why only Firefox did this, though.

Comment: Give us the full, generated HTML, not PHP.

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: By `highlight`, I guess you mean, the image has a blue overlay? correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess demo for what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/YVw58/2/

HTML Part:

```
<div id="parent">
    This is parent.
    <div id="compare">compare</div>
    <div id="childBelow">below</div>
    <div id="childUp">up</div>
</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
#parent {
    background-color: #f66;
}

#childBelow {
    background-color: #6f6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}#parent {
    background-color: #f66;
}

#childBelow {
    background-color: #6f6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#childUp {
    background-color: #66f;  
    height: 80px;      
    width: 160px; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;   
}

#compare {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
}


#childUp {
    background-color: #66f;  
    height: 80px;      
    width: 160px; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;   
}

#compare {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Of course, different result is caused by the version of web broswers. I've tested on Firefox 13.0.1, Chrome 23.0, Opera 12.0 and IE 9.0, all of which have the expected result.

Another thing you should pay attention to is that elements with smaller z-index will not receive events (e.g.: mouse click) if the event area is covered by elements with larger z-index, as shown in the demo before.

You may also have a look at z-index for more details at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/.